# How can i use search functionality in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, search

I have write code of search bar in laravel, I am doing pagination manually, but my search function is not working,

here is my code of view file

```
<form action="{{url('search-department')}}" method="GET" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Department">
    </div>
</form>
```

My Controller File Is

```
//Code For Insert record in collection
public function storeDepartment(Request $request)
{
    $department = new Department();
    $department->createdBy = $request->get('createdBy');
    $department->nameOfDepartment = $request->get('nameOfDepartment');
    $department->save();

    return redirect('list-department')->with('Success', 'Department Added Successfully!');
}

//Code For Seach
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = Input::get('q');

    if ($q != '') {
        $listOfDepartment = Department::where('nameOfDepartment', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orwhere('createdBy', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->paginate(2);

        if (count($listOfDepartment) > 0) {
            return view('pages.department')->withData($listOfDepartment);
        }
        // return view('pages.department')->withMessage("No Data Found");
    }
}
```

and route is

```
Route::get('search-department', 'DepartmentController@search');
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working? Any errors that are occurring or such things?

Comment: Actually there is no error occur, because in URL the keyword will display wha ti search for bur it won't display anything.

Comment: before search URL is like **http://127.0.0.1:8000/list-department** after search hr URL will be like **http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?q=hr** 
but it not display anyting

Comment: Can you provide your migration code?

Comment: sorry, didn't get you!!!
u mean code of view file??

Comment: No, the code of the migration file, or the structure of your database departments table.

Comment: I am not migrating it, I directly insert record in collection, I am sending code of controller,
``` public function storeDepartment(Request $request)
    {
        $department = new Department();
        $department->createdBy = $request->get('createdBy');
        $department->nameOfDepartment = $request->get('nameOfDepartment');
        $department->save();

        return redirect('list-department')->with('Success', 'Department Added Successfully!');
    }```

Comment: Don't post code in comments. If you want to add information to your question, edit the question to included it instead.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated code in question

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using version 5.7.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should try this code.

In view

```
<form role="search" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Department">
    </div>
</form>
```

And in Controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $listOfDepartment = Department::select('*');

    if(isset($request->q) && !empty($request->q))
    {
        $q = $request->q;
        $listOfDepartment = $listOfDepartment->where('nameOfDepartment', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        $listOfDepartment = $listOfDepartment->orWhere('createdBy', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
    }

    $listOfDepartment = $listOfDepartment->->paginate(2);

    if (count($listOfDepartment) > 0) {
        return view('pages.department')->withData($listOfDepartment);
    }
    // return view('pages.department')->withMessage("No Data Found");
}
```

Hope This will help you.